# How can I made a rgb led works in mplab for a PIC18F4550?

Tags: c, pic

I've tried in C to make the WS2812 works in mplab with pic18f4550, the energy reach the led, but it doesn't turn on and I can't select the led that I ant to use, but it doesn't, how can I solve this? This is the code that I'm using:
Thanks

main.c

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000UL
#include "config.h"
#include "ws2812.h"

void main(void) {
    ADCON1=0b00001111;
    TRISB=0b00000001; 
    if (energy_port==1){
             pin_strip_led=1;
            ws2812_setPixelColorLed(1, ws2812_Color(255, 0, 0));
    }
    else{ 
        pin_strip_led=0;
    }
    return;
}
```

This is what I'm using in ws2812.h:

```
#define STRIP_SIZE 8
#define pin_strip_led PORTBbits.RB1
#define energy_port PORTBbits.RB0
void ws2812_setPixelColorLed(unsigned char pixel, unsigned long color) {
    Strip_RGBData[pixel][0] = (char) (color >> 16); 
    Strip_RGBData[pixel][1] = (char) (color >> 8);
    Strip_RGBData[pixel][2] = (char) (color);
}
unsigned long ws2812_Color(unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b) {
    return ((unsigned long) r << 16) | ((unsigned long) g << 8) | b; 
}
```

Comment: You will need to be more precise for people to be able to help you. Which libraries? What are you trying to do? What's not working?

Answer (score 0):

The program shown will read port B0, set B1 to the same state, and if set, populate one row of the array Strip_RGBData (which is neither declared nor used). It will do this one time. You ask, "How can I solve this?"

A good place to start is with the WS2812 datasheet. Use it to determine how to compose the signal required to control the LEDs. In your code set up a timer to clock out the bits of that signal in compliance with the timing requirements.

After that is working, you can add a loop to read the input to select an individual LED.

Comment: Actually, I've tried to declare RGBData everywhere I though it could be used, but it didn't work and I don't know where else I can put it. According to what I read about it, I have to use a delay, I've tried but didn't work.